# How to manage codeigniter route

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am planning to define a controller as

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Lookup extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct()
{       
    parent::__construct();
    if(!($this->php_session->get('logged_in')))
    {
        redirect('login', 'refresh');
    }
}

public function add($lookup=null)
{

}

function edit($lookup=null,$id=null)
{

}

function save($lookup=null,$id=null)
{

}

function list($lookup=null)
{

}
```

This controller is for different lookup tables' operations. The lookup tables can be Education, Religion, Caste and so on...
According to the planning, the given functions have **$lookup** as parameters that will define the lookup tables to implement for.
As MVC Framework, the routing defines as: **Controller/Method/Params**

I am searching for the solution as below;
If the URI is passed as:

```
**lookup/education/add**   must route to **lookup/add/education** Where education is parameter for add function
**lookup/education/edit/1001 must route to  **lookup/edit/education/1001 where education and 1001 are parameters for edit function.
```

I would be thankful If anyone answers. Thank you!

Comment: Make bunch of controllers for each "lookup" parameter, just because in future you will be facing scalability issue. Just for an example somewhere either in your controller/model you will be forced to define what fields (columns in table X [education, religion...]) and that is the point where code will be unreadable because of too many `if()`s etc. Stick with: one method should take care of only one "task" (edit religion), rule known as "Single Responsibility Principle". Education: controller, model, views; Religion: controller, model, views...

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'll try to implement with multiple controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without questioning the sanity of the whole approach (as described in the comments), you could simply achieve this using [CI routing](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html):

```
$route['lookup/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "lookup/$2/$1/$3";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `.htaccess` or some other apache configuration file. You will need something similar to the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/lookup/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /lookup/$2/$1/$3 [L]
```

You might also want these for debugging:

```
RewriteLog /var/somewhere/some.log
RewriteLogLevel 9
```